# SELECT distinct, getting rid of Bitmap Heap Scan

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, database-performance

Given the table

```
create table a (x int, y int);
create index a_x_y on a(x, y);
```

I would expect a query like `select distinct x from a where y = 1` to use only the index, instead it uses the index to filter by y, then does a *Bitmap Heap Scan* to get all values of x.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=15.03..15.05 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.131..0.131 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on a  (cost=4.34..15.01 rows=11 width=4) (actual time=0.129..0.129 rows=0 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (y = 1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on a_x_y  (cost=0.00..4.33 rows=11 width=0) (actual time=0.125..0.125 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (y = 1)
```

What kind of index would be needed for this type of query?

Comment: Please post real plan, not empty table plan. We need at least to know how many rows do you have, how many of them are returned and how much time it takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bitmap heap scan takes 0.129 milliseconds, isn't that fast enough?

If you are thinking about an "index only scan", PostgreSQL can not yet do that.

Comment: It's fast on the empty table I used as an example. :)

Comment: Yes, I'd like to have index scan only. I basically need all the distinct values, an index should be enough to get that.

Comment: As I said: this is not possible with PostgreSQL

Comment: Indeed - seems it's not possible. If I understand correctly, the problem is that the index in this case is a lossy bitmap, which means the condition needs to be rechecked, thus the bitmap heap scan.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're filtering on the second column of the index, it won't be used for a direct index scan. If you change the index to be on y,x instead of x,y, it might give you the scan you're looking for.

Also, you may very well get a different query plan if you put actual data in your table, so you should do your testing with realistic data.

Finally, I think you are misunderstanding the bitmap scan nodes. Bitmap Heap scan doesn't mean it's doing an actual heap scan. It's using the indexes to find out which pages there are interesting rows on, and will then scan those pages only in the table in the second operation.

Comment: 1) I tried both ways - x, y and y, x. 2) I tested on my actual table with a lot of data. It happened that this empty example table had the same query plan so I posted this for simplicity. Sorry for confusion. 3) Still, the query is very slow (and I need to run it many times). I'm hoping I can somehow use just an index for this.

Comment: y,x should be usable at least in theory, so most likely it's considering it too expensive for some reason. Unless you're on a really old version of PostgreSQL, in which ase you should upgrade, of course :-) There are still some issues with cross-column correlation though, but it's hard to comment on without more detail. You might want to post your situation to the pgsql-performance mailinglist - but in that case, include the EXPLAIN ANALYZE output from your *real* query/db combination.